# git branch diverged, and discard one?

Tags: git, branch

My current status is like the following:

```
A--B--C--O1--O2--O3 (origin/master)
       \
         L1--L2--L3 (master)
```

I want origin/master to look like

```
A--B--C--L1--L2--L3 (origin/master, master)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to force a push to the server, like `git push -f origin master`. Note that this will effectively make commits `O1`, `O2` and `O3` get lost. Also, if someone else than you cloned the repo in between and still has the `A--B--C--O1--O2--O3` history, that someone needs to `git fetch` and `git reset --hard origin/master` to get your force-pushed changes, overwriting his / her local history.